# Route [map] not defined

Tags: laravel

am trying to display this view but it says the root is not defined yet i defined it on web.php file

{{ __('Search') }}

```
                <div class="collapse show">
                    <ul class="nav nav-sm flex-column">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href={{route('restaurants.map')}}>
                                {{ __('Search by nearby') }}
                            </a>
                        </li>
```

i have defined the route in the web.php file

```
Route::get('/map',function(){
    return view('restaurants.map');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are calling the route like this....you are directly given the view name 
so do changes in web file by giving name to that route...

```
<a class="nav-link" href={{route('restaurants.map')}}>
```

You have to give the name to the route like

```
Route::get('/map',function(){

return view('restaurants.map');

})->name('restaurants.map');//like this
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the route by name, not by path:

```
route('restaurants.map')
```

Means that it is looking for a route named `"restaurants.map"`.

Add a name to the route like so:

```
Route::get('/map',function(){
    return view('restaurants.map');
})->name('restaurants.map');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your view routing to `restaurants.map` is configured in `.web.php`; you don't need to link directly to that from the navbar. Instead, you should link to the `GET` parameter defined in `Route::get`:

```
<a class="nav-link" href={{route('/map')}}>
```

Comment: Route [/map] not defined. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Tafuta_restaurant\resources\views\layouts\navbars\sidebar.blade.php)    getting this error